# Does Shilov's Linear Algebra cover SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I'm teaching myself Georgi E. Shilov's *Linear Algebra*, and have just finished chapter 6 except the final two starred sections. So far, I haven't seen Singular Value Decomposition (SVD). I skimmed the rest of the book, and looked it up in the Index, but had no luck. I'd like to quit studying the book prematurely if it turns out not to cover the subject. You information is valuable. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the table of contents, it seems unlikely. It's not in the index either. Why do you want to study the SVD? I would suggest Golub and Van Loan *"Matrix Computations"*, a well-known reference on numerical linear algebra, or Åke Björck *"Numerical Methods in Matrix Computations"*, also very good.

Comment: It's in Trefethen and Bau (https://books.google.com/books/about/Numerical_Linear_Algebra.html?id=JaPtxOytY7kC) . Lecture 4,5, and 31

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm studying Goodfellow et al.'s _Deep Learning_, which introduces SVD but doesn't elaborate on it. The authors "highly recommend" Shilov's _Linear Algebra_, so I thought it should cover the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. SVD had yet to become a textbook topic in the English speaking world when Shilov's book was first published (1971). I think it entered the textbook scene by virtues of Gilbert Strang's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* and Golub and Van Loan's *Matrix Computations*, which were published at later times.